# Return names which dont exist in the database from the list provided

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

Let's assume I have a list of company names like so:

```
CompA
CompB
CompC
```

How would I go about only returning the names which don't exist in the database.

```
SELECT * FROM db.companies dc WHERE dc.name NOT IN ('CompA','CompB','CompC')
```

I have tried using `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` but this returns all the company names which are not in the list but present in the database, but I need only the names from the specified list which does not exist.

So for example if `CompC` was not an existing company it should just return `CompC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your list of companies into a table, and then query from it.

```
create temp table tmp_companies (name varchar(100)); 
insert into tmp_companies 
values 
('CompA'), 
('CompB'), 
('CompC'); 

select * 
from tmp_companies c
where not exist (
select 1 
from db.companies dc
where dc.name = c.name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a CTE with contain all company names which you want to check. Then query from defined CTE.

```
WITH list_names AS (
    SELECT 'CompA' as name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CompB' as name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CompC' as name
)
SELECT ln.* 
FROM list_names ln
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM db.companies dc WHERE dc.name = ln.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a temp table, abit more complex and requiring a new line for each name you want to search:

select
case when (select count(*) from db.companies dc where dc.name = 'CompA') > 0 then 'exists' else 'not found' end CompA,
case when (select count(*) from db.companies dc where dc.name = 'CompB') > 0 then 'exists' else 'not found' end  CompB